# How can I run a top level async / await function with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, async-await

My file is:

```
import * as fs from 'fs'

async function loadModels() {
    console.log('here i am!')
    const modelFiles = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/models')
    console.log(modelFiles)
}


(async () => {
    loadModels()
})()
```

And in `package.json`, I have:

```
"fixtures": "tsc fixtures/index"
```

So when I run `yarn fixtures`, I get:

```
yarn fixtures
yarn run v1.22.4
$ tsc fixtures/index
✨  Done in 8.78s.
```

Why won't my `loadModels` run?

Comment: why do you need async/await for the filesystem `fs`?

Comment: `loadModels` _does_ run with this structure. [See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIwDbuAEwFl18BTbEACgEoYBvAWACgZWZhtSAnZSgcgAW3UjFTsAtgEI+1ZgF9mippVCRYNGAF4AfPWZsceIiXJVZTOdRpA).

Comment: On a side note: There is no need for the async keyword anywhere in this code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tsc` is only compiling your TypeScript file, it's not executing it

to execute your TypeScript file you can use `ts-node` [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node)

and then in your `package.json`:

```
"fixtures": "ts-node fixtures/index"
```

Comment: It's also possible to build-and-run instead of using `ts-node` package. In your package.json: `"fixtures": "tsc&&node fixtures/index.js"`.

Comment: Yes of course it's possible, but i guess this file is only for development purposes so it's shouldn't be compiled into final application